# jQuery PrintThis in ASP.net Core color not visible

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, colors, summernote, printthis

I have an issue with the jQuery PrintThis plugin in ASP.net Core.

I create a html string with formats with summernote, for example a table with yellow font color. If I print this with jQuery plugin every thing is displayed right, but the color is not displayed. The color is still black.

Can anyone help me here?

Thank you in advance
Cini

UPDATE:
Here is my code:
the Index.cshtml where I call the function and the css from the PrintThis plugin.

```js
/*
 * printThis v1.15.1
 * @desc Printing plug-in for jQuery
 * @author Jason Day
 *
 * Resources (based on):
 * - jPrintArea: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jPrintArea
 * - jqPrint: https://github.com/permanenttourist/jquery.jqprint
 * - Ben Nadal: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT licence:
 *              http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * (c) Jason Day 2015-2019
 *
 * Usage:
 *
 *  $("#mySelector").printThis({
 *      debug: false,                   // show the iframe for debugging
 *      importCSS: true,                // import parent page css
 *      importStyle: false,             // import style tags
 *      printContainer: true,           // grab outer container as well as the contents of the selector
 *      loadCSS: "path/to/my.css",      // path to additional css file - use an array [] for multiple
 *      pageTitle: "",                  // add title to print page
 *      removeInline: false,            // remove all inline styles from print elements
 *      removeInlineSelector: "body *", // custom selectors to filter inline styles. removeInline must be true
 *      printDelay: 333,                // variable print delay
 *      header: null,                   // prefix to html
 *      footer: null,                   // postfix to html
 *      base: false,                    // preserve the BASE tag, or accept a string for the URL
 *      formValues: true,               // preserve input/form values
 *      canvas: false,                  // copy canvas elements
 *      doctypeString: '...',           // enter a different doctype for older markup
 *      removeScripts: false,           // remove script tags from print content
 *      copyTagClasses: false           // copy classes from the html & body tag
 *      beforePrintEvent: null,         // callback function for printEvent in iframe
 *      beforePrint: null,              // function called before iframe is filled
 *      afterPrint: null                // function called before iframe is removed
 *  });
 *
 * Notes:
 *  - the loadCSS will load additional CSS (with or without @media print) into the iframe, adjusting layout
 */
;
(function($) {

    function appendContent($el, content) {
        if (!content) return;

        // Simple test for a jQuery element
        $el.append(content.jquery ? content.clone() : content);
    }

    function appendBody($body, $element, opt) {
        // Clone for safety and convenience
        // Calls clone(withDataAndEvents = true) to copy form values.
        var $content = $element.clone(opt.formValues);

        if (opt.formValues) {
            // Copy original select and textarea values to their cloned counterpart
            // Makes up for inability to clone select and textarea values with clone(true)
            copyValues($element, $content, 'select, textarea');
        }

        if (opt.removeScripts) {
            $content.find('script').remove();
        }

        if (opt.printContainer) {
            // grab $.selector as container
            $content.appendTo($body);
        } else {
            // otherwise just print interior elements of container
            $content.each(function() {
                $(this).children().appendTo($body)
            });
        }
    }

    // Copies values from origin to clone for passed in elementSelector
    function copyValues(origin, clone, elementSelector) {
        var $originalElements = origin.find(elementSelector);

        clone.find(elementSelector).each(function(index, item) {
            $(item).val($originalElements.eq(index).val());
        });
    }

    var opt;
    $.fn.printThis = function(options) {
        opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.printThis.defaults, options);
        var $element = this instanceof jQuery ? this : $(this);

        var strFrameName = "printThis-" + (new Date()).getTime();

        if (window.location.hostname !== document.domain && navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i)) {
            // Ugly IE hacks due to IE not inheriting document.domain from parent
            // checks if document.domain is set by comparing the host name against document.domain
            var iframeSrc = "javascript:document.write(\"<head><script>document.domain=\\\"" + document.domain + "\\\";</s" + "cript></head><body></body>\")";
            var printI = document.createElement('iframe');
            printI.name = "printIframe";
            printI.id = strFrameName;
            printI.className = "MSIE";
            document.body.appendChild(printI);
            printI.src = iframeSrc;

        } else {
            // other browsers inherit document.domain, and IE works if document.domain is not explicitly set
            var $frame = $("<iframe id='" + strFrameName + "' name='printIframe' />");
            $frame.appendTo("body");
        }

        var $iframe = $("#" + strFrameName);

        // show frame if in debug mode
        if (!opt.debug) $iframe.css({
            position: "absolute",
            width: "0px",
            height: "0px",
            left: "-600px",
            top: "-600px"
        });

        // before print callback
        if (typeof opt.beforePrint === "function") {
            opt.beforePrint();
        }

        // $iframe.ready() and $iframe.load were inconsistent between browsers
        setTimeout(function() {

            // Add doctype to fix the style difference between printing and render
            function setDocType($iframe, doctype){
                var win, doc;
                win = $iframe.get(0);
                win = win.contentWindow || win.contentDocument || win;
                doc = win.document || win.contentDocument || win;
                doc.open();
                doc.write(doctype);
                doc.close();
            }

            if (opt.doctypeString){
                setDocType($iframe, opt.doctypeString);
            }

            var $doc = $iframe.contents(),
                $head = $doc.find("head"),
                $body = $doc.find("body"),
                $base = $('base'),
                baseURL;

            // add base tag to ensure elements use the parent domain
            if (opt.base === true && $base.length > 0) {
                // take the base tag from the original page
                baseURL = $base.attr('href');
            } else if (typeof opt.base === 'string') {
                // An exact base string is provided
                baseURL = opt.base;
            } else {
                // Use the page URL as the base
                baseURL = document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.host;
            }

            $head.append('<base href="' + baseURL + '">');

            // import page stylesheets
            if (opt.importCSS) $("link[rel=stylesheet]").each(function() {
                var href = $(this).attr("href");
                if (href) {
                    var media = $(this).attr("media") || "all";
                    $head.append("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + href + "' media='" + media + "'>");
                }
            });

            // import style tags
            if (opt.importStyle) $("style").each(function() {
                $head.append(this.outerHTML);
            });

            // add title of the page
            if (opt.pageTitle) $head.append("<title>" + opt.pageTitle + "</title>");

            // import additional stylesheet(s)
            if (opt.loadCSS) {
                if ($.isArray(opt.loadCSS)) {
                    jQuery.each(opt.loadCSS, function(index, value) {
                        $head.append("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + this + "'>");
                    });
                } else {
                    $head.append("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + opt.loadCSS + "'>");
                }
            }

            var pageHtml = $('html')[0];

            // CSS VAR in html tag when dynamic apply e.g.  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--foo", bar);
            $doc.find('html').prop('style', pageHtml.style.cssText);

            // copy 'root' tag classes
            var tag = opt.copyTagClasses;
            if (tag) {
                tag = tag === true ? 'bh' : tag;
                if (tag.indexOf('b') !== -1) {
                    $body.addClass($('body')[0].className);
                }
                if (tag.indexOf('h') !== -1) {
                    $doc.find('html').addClass(pageHtml.className);
                }
            }

            // print header
            appendContent($body, opt.header);

            if (opt.canvas) {
                // add canvas data-ids for easy access after cloning.
                var canvasId = 0;
                // .addBack('canvas') adds the top-level element if it is a canvas.
                $element.find('canvas').addBack('canvas').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('data-printthis', canvasId++);
                });
            }

            appendBody($body, $element, opt);

            if (opt.canvas) {
                // Re-draw new canvases by referencing the originals
                $body.find('canvas').each(function(){
                    var cid = $(this).data('printthis'),
                        $src = $('[data-printthis="' + cid + '"]');

                    this.getContext('2d').drawImage($src[0], 0, 0);

                    // Remove the markup from the original
                    if ($.isFunction($.fn.removeAttr)) {
                        $src.removeAttr('data-printthis');
                    } else {
                        $.each($src, function(i, el) {
                            el.removeAttribute('data-printthis');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

            // remove inline styles
            if (opt.removeInline) {
                // Ensure there is a selector, even if it's been mistakenly removed
                var selector = opt.removeInlineSelector || '*';
                // $.removeAttr available jQuery 1.7+
                if ($.isFunction($.removeAttr)) {
                    $body.find(selector).removeAttr("style");
                } else {
                    $body.find(selector).attr("style", "");
                }
            }

            // print "footer"
            appendContent($body, opt.footer);

            // attach event handler function to beforePrint event
            function attachOnBeforePrintEvent($iframe, beforePrintHandler) {
                var win = $iframe.get(0);
                win = win.contentWindow || win.contentDocument || win;

                if (typeof beforePrintHandler === "function") {
                    if ('matchMedia' in win) {
                        win.matchMedia('print').addListener(function(mql) {
                            if(mql.matches)  beforePrintHandler();
                        });
                    } else {
                        win.onbeforeprint = beforePrintHandler;
                    }
                }
            }
            attachOnBeforePrintEvent($iframe, opt.beforePrintEvent);

            setTimeout(function() {
                if ($iframe.hasClass("MSIE")) {
                    // check if the iframe was created with the ugly hack
                    // and perform another ugly hack out of neccessity
                    window.frames["printIframe"].focus();
                    $head.append("<script>  window.print(); </s" + "cript>");
                } else {
                    // proper method
                    if (document.queryCommandSupported("print")) {
                        $iframe[0].contentWindow.document.execCommand("print", false, null);
                    } else {
                        $iframe[0].contentWindow.focus();
                        $iframe[0].contentWindow.print();
                    }
                }

                // remove iframe after print
                if (!opt.debug) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $iframe.remove();

                    }, 1000);
                }

                // after print callback
                if (typeof opt.afterPrint === "function") {
                    opt.afterPrint();
                }

            }, opt.printDelay);

        }, 333);

    };

    // defaults
    $.fn.printThis.defaults = {
        debug: false,               // show the iframe for debugging
        importCSS: true,            // import parent page css
        importStyle: false,         // import style tags
        printContainer: true,       // print outer container/$.selector
        loadCSS: "",                // path to additional css file - use an array [] for multiple
        pageTitle: "",              // add title to print page
        removeInline: false,        // remove inline styles from print elements
        removeInlineSelector: "*",  // custom selectors to filter inline styles. removeInline must be true
        printDelay: 333,            // variable print delay
        header: null,               // prefix to html
        footer: null,               // postfix to html
        base: false,                // preserve the BASE tag or accept a string for the URL
        formValues: true,           // preserve input/form values
        canvas: false,              // copy canvas content
        doctypeString: '<!DOCTYPE html>', // enter a different doctype for older markup
        removeScripts: false,       // remove script tags from print content
        copyTagClasses: false,      // copy classes from the html & body tag
        beforePrintEvent: null,     // callback function for printEvent in iframe
        beforePrint: null,          // function called before iframe is filled
        afterPrint: null            // function called before iframe is removed
    };
})(jQuery);
```

```html
   @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<div class="container">
    Your Content
    <p><font color="#ff0000">Hello World</font></p><p><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Hello World</span></p>


</div>

<button id="print"> Print this </button>


<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/printThis/printThis.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#print').on("click", function () {
            $('.container').printThis({
                importCSS: true,
                importStyle: true,
                removeInline: false});

        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your code, try to set the `importCSS` and `importStyle` to `true`.

```
$('#advanced').on("click", function () {
    $('#table2print').printThis({
        importCSS: true,
        importStyle: true,
        removeInline: false
    });
});
```

Besides, which kind of browser are you using to print the table? Perhaps the issue is related to the browser setting. For example, if using Google browser to print the table, there have a Color selector in the print page, remember to select the **Color** option.

[image]

Besides, if still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I tried to set the attributes mentioned by you, but it still doesn't work. I also checked if the Color option in my browser is checked. I added the code to my question...